# socket.connect throw exception

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0, system.net

I want to learn socket programming in C#, and related settings.
I've download a demo from a site.
when i set Remote Host IP address to my local address it connect to server (my pc) and send receive works.

[image]

however when i set Remote Host IP address to my router external IP, i doesn't connect and throw exception: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 91.99.166.161:300"

[image]

i set port forwarding in my router.
what's wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Either your port forwarding configuration is incorrect, there's a firewall in the way, or the host you're forwarding to is not listening on the destination port.

Comment: I've disable firewall. this is my port forwarding configuration: external port start:300 , external port end:300, internal port start:300 , internal port end:300 , protocol: tcp , Server IP Address:192.168.1.2, and I've started listening

Comment: If you want to add more details, please edit your original question.